# Intellij IDEA JPA ORM mapped entity convert to an INSERT SQL statement automatically

Tags: hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, orm

I have some huge entities which are annotated JPA. I have Spring test scripts which run automatically, and to populate these, I have an SQL script which runs. Currently, I'm typing my entity data into my script by hand.

My IDE is Intellij, and I'm wondering if there an automatic way to generate:

```
 INSERT INTO BLAH (X,Y,X) VALUES ('','','');
```

from

```
 @ENTITY 
 @TABLE (name = blah)

 @COLUMN
 String x;
 @COLUMN 
 String y;
 @COLUMN 
 String x;
 @COLUMN
```

Intellij version is 13.2. I realise I can get the DDL from IntelliJ database, and edit this down, but it's still hand work!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found it - guess I should have looked harder before posting.

Right click the table in Intellij database tab, select save to File, select INSERT SQL statement.

Hope that helps.

However, if you have used 
@Column(name = ServerJPAConstants.MY_COL_NAME_THING) , you will find that the table names match literally 'my_col_name_thing' , but not the value of MY_COL_NAME_THING (which in my case is a String constant.)

Comment: Isn't that working off of the already-created table, and not the entity?